# Batch command to replace specific text

Tags: batch-file

I have to write a batch file that search for a specific line in a file, and replace it with the filename.

To be specific, one file:

```
data
data
data
ABCD xyz <- this is the line that i have to replace. abcd always the same xyz always different
data
data
```

i'd like to change the xyz value to the name of the file without extension. So if the file is blabla.tpo then the file have look like:

```
data
data
ABCD blabla
data
....
```

I hope you guys can help me out. I'm not a programmer, these are 3d files and i have 1000 of them. I already googled every way, wrote hundreds of non working batch files. Tried FAR, notepad++ and who knows how much more without succes. If the program can do it, then i have to open files one by one, or it can't insert the filename, only exact string...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a string and replace specific letters in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085650/find-a-string-and-replace-specific-letters-in-batch-file)

Comment: It is a duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/) Some tools in referenced topic can even run on multiple files. And of course there are also text editors which support a replace in all files of a directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl if you have it:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^(ABCD ).*$/) { print "$1blabla\n"; } else { print $_; }' inputfile.txt
```

The shell itself is not terribly great for that sort of task. You can probably do line-by-line reading (e.g. via `read` in Bash), but the replacement logic isn't that refined or powerful as that of Perl.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this pearl can batch do this? I mean there is a folder with 100 file and every file have to base on this method.

Comment: @VicziánSándor: Sure: `for i in *; do perl ... $i > $i.output; done` etc. The Windows shell has a similar construction.